# how to update object which has OneToOne relationship in django?

Tags: django

I need to update the integer-field in every time I send the request with post method I tried that with the three ways but I couldn't make it. the problem is that when I send a request the request is sent successfully but the data doesn't save. I asked this question before but I didn't get the answer so I hope if anyone can help me I will be thanks

match_statics/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from match.models import Main
from .models import Statistics
from .forms import StaticForm
from django.db.models import F


def player_statics(request, pk):
    form = StaticForm()
    statics = Statistics.objects.filter(main_id=pk)
    main_pk = Main.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'short_pos' in request.POST:
            form = StaticForm(request.POST, instance=Main.objects.get(pk=pk))
            if form.is_valid():
                # static = Statistics.objects.filter(main_id=pk).update(short_pass=form.cleaned_data['short_pass'] + 1)
                # static = Statistics.objects.filter(main_id=pk).update(short_pass=F('short_pass') + 1)
                form.short_pass = form.cleaned_data['short_pass']
                form.short_pass += 1
                form.save()
    context = {'form': form, 'statics': statics, 'main_pk': main_pk}
    return render(request, 'match_statics/player_statics.html', context)
```

match_statics/player_statics.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Player Statics</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="match-statics">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'match_statics:player_statics' main_pk.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="buttons">
                    <h2>Pass Position</h2>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {{ field.as_hidden }}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div>{{ statics }}</div>
                    <input type="submit" name="short_pos">
                    <input type="submit" name="long_pos">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

match_statics/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from match.models import PlayerName
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Statistics(models.Model):
    # main = models.ForeignKey(PlayerName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='static_field')
    main = models.OneToOneField(PlayerName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    short_pass = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    long_pass = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.main.pk


def create_player_name(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Statistics.objects.create(main=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(receiver=create_player_name, sender=PlayerName)
```

match_statics/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Statistics


class StaticForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Statistics
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['main']
```

**Edit:**

```
AttributeError at /match_statistics/player_statics/59/
'Main' object has no attribute 'statistics'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/match_statistics/player_statics/59/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Main' object has no attribute 'statistics'
Exception Location: /media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/Essam Alaa/website2/website/match_statics/views.py in player_statics, line 14
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/Essam '
 'Alaa/website2/website',
 '/usr/bin/python3',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 29 Jul 2020 23:33:15 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/Essam Alaa/website2/website/match_statics/views.py in player_statics
            form = StaticForm(request.POST, instance=main_pk.statistics) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
medoabdin

GET
No GET data

POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'vfNLC1mN2Uk5MeuJhz7dtLGty076WVXHlonIq0AAsWTS4z1F4lDWRneLhOJ25FxF'
short_pass  
'0'
long_pass   
'0'
short_pos   
'Submit'
```

Answer (score 0):

`StaticForm` by that name, I am assuming it is created from `Statistics` not `Main` object. So you should pass that to the `StaticForm` when making a POST request. So you can try the following solution:

```
form = StaticForm(request.POST, instance=Main.objects.get(pk=pk).statistics)
if form.is_valid():
   instance = form.save(commit=False)
   instance.short_pass += 1
   instance.save()
```

Here `Main.objects.get(pk=pk).statistics` will return the `Statistics` object due to `OneToOne` relation. Alternatively you can use `main_pk.statistics`.

Comment: actually I cannot understand exactly what is that mean but I tried as a copy-paste what you sent me and the error is raised as AttributeError because of that line: form = StaticForm(request.POST, instance=Main.objects.get(pk=main_pk.statistics).statistics), knowing that the valid became unknown plus the bound is False

Comment: It should be `main_pk.statistics`, not `Main.objects.get(pk=main_pk.statistics).statistics`

Comment: ok, now I tried main_pk.statistics but I got the same exception with the same validation

Comment: I have no mind if I sent you the full project on GitHub to know why of this error

Comment: can you add the full error stacktrace on the question please?

Comment: I edit the post you can check it also if you need to see the code real I upload my whole code in Github please check this link: https://github.com/AbdelhamedAbdin/match

Comment: Can you share your models `PlayerName`, `Main` and what is the relationship between Main and Statistics?